# Svelte-routing links removes base path in electron

Tags: javascript, routes, electron, svelte

I am working on an Electron.js application, utilizing Svelte as my frontend framework.
I am using the svelte-routing library for routing:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="">
      //Home Page
      <Link to="subpath">
    </Route>

      <Route path="subpath">
        //Subpath
      </Route>
</Router>
```

When a link is clicked it removes the base path, leaving only the subpath:
I get: `file:///subpath` instead of `file:///path/to/project/public/index.html` in `window.location`.

The routing still works but when electron performs a hot reload all I get is a blank screen, and an error:
`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///subpath`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hash routing would solve this. For example, instead of using a path `/about`, you'd use `#/about`. In electron terms, that means `file:///path/to/index.html#/about`

Unfortunately `svelte-routing` does not support hash `#` routing.

One router that expressly supports it is [`@jamen/svelte-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jamen/svelte-router) (there may be others).

Here is an example usage of `@james/svelte-router`:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import {Router} from '@jamen/svelte-router'
  import Home from './screens/Home.svelte'
  import About from './screens/About.svelte'

  const routes = {
    "/": Home,
    "/about": About
  }
</script>

<Router {routes}/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks great. Just how could I pass arguments to the component routes? It's not specified in the docs

Comment: hmm, looks like this router doesn't support params like `/post/:id`... didnt realize when I posted the answer.

Comment: I meant passing params to a component like HTML, like `href=` and svelte bindings. Basically routing to more than a single component.